# Positioning labels in center of clipped polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, labeling, centroids

I am using ArcMap 10.1  and would like to label a polygon layer that i have clipped.  It appears that the label is set for the geometric center of the polygon that falls outside of the clipping.

Comment: Did you re-export the clipped feature class/shapefile?

Comment: I am clipping through the data frame properties

Comment: export the resultant clipped features into a new feature class or shapefile, then the labeling should take into account the new geometries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you clip the polygon you should export it to a new shapefile or import it to a feature class inside of a geodatabase and you should be fine. The *[clip tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Clip%20(Analysis)) (analysis)* will make this unnecessary but from what you are explaining I suspect you are using *[Clip](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1x6Pki_DJAhUP92MKHSJOAyUQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebhelp.esri.com%2Farcgisdesktop%2F9.3%2Findex.cfm%3FTopicName%3DClipping_features&usg=AFQjCNGw3DAn8_u4xhxRUKQpg_UQpk7zag&sig2=3AQBMK4W33Pd0jano3jKkw&bvm=bv.110151844,d.cGc)* in *Editor* as this should not happen with Clip in a tool.